# Mounting a CDROM in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, mount

I'm using a software that needs to read data from a cdrom. The instructions say to
mount the cdrom (mount /mnt/cdrom). I understand that I need to mount the cdrom to /mnt/cdrom.

I created a folder "cdrom" under "mnt". Then I tried to mount the cdrom by typing:

sudo mount /media/ /mnt/cdrom/

This didn't work. Under "media" I have another folder with the actual cd content so I
tried to mount it too, but again with no success. I keep getting an error that "media is not a block device".

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`mount /dev/sr0 /mnt/cdrom`

You need to use the cd-rom's block device to mount.  It's most commonly sr0 on modern distributions.

But if your CD is already mounted to media automatically, you don't need to do this.  You just need to point the program to the contents of the CD in /media.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot!

I couldn't point the program to media because I don't have the source and it seems like it's hard-coded there.

Answer (score 2):

You normally mount block devices (or in some cases, files containing equivalent data).

You can, however, link two directories using a *bind mount*:

```
mount --bind "/media/My CD-ROM" /mnt/cdrom
```

(A similar effect could be reached by symlinking `/mnt/cdrom` to the intended target, too.)